Where can I find a Mercenary Guild envoy?
I'm exploring the new space station's layout (after some recent updates), but I was only able to find a Merchants Guild envoy.
Where are Mercenary Guild envoys located? I have a few pirate transponders now and I want to redeem the related rewards.
Do I have to check other space stations in other systems in order to get a different one?

According to every reasonably recent* result that I can find on Google, guild envoys are all the same within a given region. To find a different envoy, it is not enough to travel to a different system. You must travel to a different region.
Strictly speaking, I can't find a strong authority for this. But I can tell you that I've warped to many systems controlled by various races within a single region, and they all have the same guild envoy, regardless of dominant race.
To determine the region a star system is in, expand its info card in the galaxy map. The region name will appear just below the star's name. If every star near you is in the same region, then just travel in a straight line for long enough, and you'll hit a different region. Regions typically have between 200 and 600 stars, so it should not take more than a few jumps at most.

* Post-Orbital.

The mission board is available on the ground floor. They present a random set of quest, some generic, some guild specific. They are the equivalent of the old left most mission giver (the one next to the shop terminal) in the old pre-update layout.
The Guild envoys are now limited to one guild per station. I didn't check if Vy'keen always have the mercenary guild,  Korvax the explorer and Gek the merchant one, but I would not be surprised if this was the case.
Just remember that the reward are on a "by system" level: you can get the reward in on system and then again in another for the same guild...
... and actually loading a restore point on the station seem to reset the "already got this reward" flag, so you could get infinite free slot expansions if you wanted.

@pinckerman I expect that yes, but I prefer to avoid giving it for granted until I can confirm it. As you can see the wiki is pretty in a bad state, the relative page is full of outdate info
